# Crear un acceso directo que ejecute un archivo en Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un programa hecho en Node.js que está en la ruta:

```
D:\Dropbox\js-arduino\LEDJavascript\index.js
```

Obviamente lo ejecuto desde la terminal de la siguiente manera:

```
node index.js
```

¿Hay una manera de crear un script que solo al darle doble click, empiece a correr el programa? Para evitar el trabajo de estar entrando hasta la ubicación de mis archivos del proyecto a través de la consola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba haciendo un script en `batch` de esta forma:

```
node D:\Dropbox\js-arduino\LEDJavascript\index.js
```

Lo guardas con la extensión `.bat` y lo puedes ejecutar desde donde quieras